# Why hoisting in this situation isn't allowed?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I find an example in w3school like this:

```
carName = "Saab";
let carName = "Volvo";
```

So after compile it would be like this:

```
let carName;
carName = "Saab";
carName = "Volvo";
```

Why is this wrong?

Comment: `So after compile it would be like this:` are you sure? you'd actually get an error with that code ... something like `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'carName' before initialization` - so, your question makes absolutely no sense

Comment: `let` and `const` are hoisted, but with at temporal dead zone.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now! Silly me asking a question for such ez problem.

Comment: Variables declared with let and const are also hoisted but, unlike var , are not initialized with a default value. An exception will be thrown if a variable declared with let or const is read before it is initialized.